# When a caster affected by the Slow spell doesn't complete the spell they're casting, does it consume the spell slot and material components?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, spell-components, spell-slots

One of the effect of [*slow*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/slow) on a creature is (emphasis mine):

> If the creature attempts to cast a spell with a casting time of 1 action, roll a d20. On an 11 or higher, the spell doesn't take effect until the creature's next turn, and the creature must use its action on that turn to complete the spell. **If it can't, the spell is wasted.**

**Does it simply mean the spell fails, and that I don't expend a spell slot and material components since I haven't completed the casting?**

Comment: Related: "[Does a countered spell cost a spell slot?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/86783)" and "[Does a countered spell expend its material components?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/86795)" and "[If a spell cast from a Spell Scroll is Counterspelled, is the scroll consumed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/86366)" and "[How does Slow interact with Concentration spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/104898)"

Comment: Another related question about using material components: [If I have a single diamond worth more than 300 gp, does Revivify consume the whole diamond?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177293/38834)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### *Wasted* indicates a loss of resources.

Searching Merriam Webster for the applicable definition of “[waste](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/waste)”, I found these two that seem most relevant:

> a : to spend or use carelessly : SQUANDER
>
> > *waste* valuable resources
>
> b : to allow to be used inefficiently or become dissipated

If the spell slot was not lost, it wouldn’t make sense to say the spell was “wasted”. “Wasted” indicates that something is lost, squandered. In this case, the resource used to cast the spell is wasted - a spell slot (and components, if applicable).